# How to force vim to syntax-highlight a file as html?

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, vim

How do I set vim's syntax highlighting to treat a file extension as an html file?

I'm using ez template, so the file's extension is `.ezt`.  But a lot of it is normal html code.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can also put this into your .vimrc:

```
au BufReadPost *.ezt set syntax=html
```

Comment: E216: No such group or event: BufLoad *.ezt set syntax=html ... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: In my experience this approach will fail if you give an ***exact*** filename e.g. `.myspecialdotfile`. It needs a star in it somewhere to work, even if it's theoretically not necessary.

Comment: I have this in my `.vimrc` file for Dockerfiles that have extensions for different purposes.
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead Dockerfile\* set filetype=docker
Just using `Dockerfile*` prevents syntax highlighting from working when using `vi Dockerfile` - adding the backslash  allows it to work for `Dockerfile` / `Dockerfile.something` and `Dockerfilesomething`

Answer (score 307):

```
:set syntax=html
```

Comment: Might help to know that running `:set syntax` will return the currently applied file highlighting

Comment: that didn't help for the .pug file...

Answer (score 37):

To make it automatic, add this line to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.ezt set filetype=html
```

If you want to just do it for the current file, then type:

```
:set filetype=html
```

You could also substitute `syntax` instead of `filetype`, but [`filetype` affects more things than `syntax`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Filetype.vim) (including syntax highlighting, indenting rules, and plugins), so generally you should use `filetype` unless you only want to affect `syntax`.

Answer (score 35):

Take a look at this [Vim wikia topic](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Forcing_Syntax_Coloring_for_files_with_odd_extensions). Some useful tips:

- As other answers have mentioned, you can use the vim set command to set syntax. `:set syntax=<type>` where `<type>` is something like `perl`, `html`, `php`, etc.
- There is another mechanism that can be used to control syntax highlighting called `filetype`, or `ft` for short. Similar to syntax, you give it a type like this: `:set filetype=html`. Other filetypes are `perl`, `php`, etc.
- Sometimes vim "forgets" what syntax to use, especially if you're mixing things like php and html together. Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (`<C-L>`) to get vim to refresh the highlighting.

Answer (score 21):

Note that `:set syntax=xml` highlights properly but seems to fail when one is attempting to autoindent the file (i.e. running `gg=G`).

When I switched to `:set filetype=xml`, the highlighting worked properly and the file indented properly.

Answer (score 21):

In a .php file (or a html file), you could use a [Vim Modeline](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic) to force certain commands or settings:

```
 1 /* vim: syntax=javascript
 2  *
 3  * .submit_norefresh()
 ~
 ~
```

Comment: You mean Modeline

Comment: Sometimes the syntax-related `au ...` settings in my `~/.vimrc` get ignored for certain files (presumably due to modified metadata?). Other than copying that file content to a fresh file, setting a modeline at the top of that file works. E.g., for a BASH script, adding a second line, `# vim: syntax=sh` after the shebang (first line: `#!/bin/bash`) seems to work, reliably. Since it's basically a "comment", I just include both lines in my `sbb` ("shebang bash") snippet.

Comment: Yes, having something like `# vim:ft=dosini` or `# vim:ft=sh` as the first line works for me as well. Especially useful if it's a config file with no file extension.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was:

```
:syntax on
```