# Enable Vim syntax highlighting regardless of filename extension

Tags: vim

I am opening a file with no extension with `vim`, say:

```
myappsetting.conf
```

This file is actually a `*.ini` file, with following formats:

```
[setting_a]
yo = 1234
```

How can I enable `vim` to correctly display this file with colour with the correct format?

I am looking for some `vim` command like:

```
:set syntaxtype=ini
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853028/how-to-force-vim-to-syntax-highlight-a-file-as-html

Comment: That one is for one particular file type. That solution does not work either.

Comment: Please try before saying it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this to reset the syntax:

```
:set syn=ini
```

Comment: The color still hasn't come up. :-(

Comment: Do you have a `~/.vim/syntax/ini.vim` file?

Comment: Type **`:verbose set syn=ini`** to check if there's a error message.

Comment: A file called `abc.ini` would display correctly, but when I rename the file into `abc.conf`, even after the command `:set syn=ini` it does not work.

Comment: open `abc.ini` in vim, then type **`:set syn?`** to check the syntax type.

Comment: Thanks kev. `:verbose set syn=ini` tells me the `ini.vim` file is missing. Interesting though that a regular `*.ini` file would not require `ini.vim` to display correctly.

Comment: where is the `ini.vim` in your system? In `Windows`, it usually in `C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\syntax` or `C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\syntax`

Answer (score 8):

Put this in your .vimrc :

```
au BufReadPost *.conf set syntax=ini
```

Comment: Wouldn't this normally be `dosini` rather than just `ini` ?

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue on my Arch linux desktop.  I found these files owned by the `vim-runtime` package.

```
$ pacman -Qlq vim-runtime | grep dosini
/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/dosini.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/dosini.vim
```

Based on that, I found I could get `dosini` highlighting either by setting the syntax (syn) or the filetype (ft).

```
:set ft=dosini
```

You can have this happen automatically with a vim modeline.  Add this to the last line of your file.

```
# vim: set ft=dosini :
```

Comment: For the modeline to work, though, you have to enable it. Issue `set modeline` in a vim session or (better yet) add `set modeline` to your `~/.vimrc`    http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic

Comment: If `modeline` is enabled you can also just use `# vim: ft=dosini` (notice does not require "set" ) and it doesn't need to be the last line - I usually use it as the first line

Answer (score 0):

Work for me for *.conf, in .vimrc file:

```
au BufReadPost *.conf set syntax=dosini
```