# Vim syntax file not being applied

Tags: vim

I have added a scala syntax file from https://github.com/derekwyatt/vim-scala/blob/master/syntax/scala.vim  as `~/.vim/syntax/scala.vim` to an ubuntu system

```
$ ll ~/.vim/syntax/scala.vim
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steve steve 11202 Dec 11 07:48 /home/steve/.vim/syntax/scala.vim
```

But `vim MyFile.scala` is still vanilla white - no syntax applied. Any hints here?

Comment: You need the whole thing.

Comment: @romainl  Please expand on your comment - *what* whole thing?

Comment: It is about html but should help for scala as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853028/how-to-force-vim-to-syntax-highlight-a-file-as-html

Comment: [The whole plugin](https://github.com/derekwyatt/vim-scala) of course.

Comment: @romainl  The OP stated the objective is only for the *syntax* handler: not an entirely new plugin.

Comment: You need other parts of that plugin for that syntax script to do anything, **therefore** you must install *the whole thing*.

Comment: @romainl ah I see..  I don't want that. Have opted instead for https://github.com/jergason/scala.vim  which fits better with my simpler use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to tell Vim to apply this syntax file for Scala files.

[`ftdetect/scala.vim`](https://github.com/derekwyatt/vim-scala/blob/master/ftdetect/scala.vim) contains the logic for detecting whether this file is a Scale file, and will set the `filetype` accordingly. This will also set the `syntax` setting. If you add this file, things should work.

In addition to that, you'll almost certainly also want:

- [`ftplugin/scala.vim`](https://github.com/derekwyatt/vim-scala/blob/master/ftplugin/scala.vim) – this sets various settings that make sense for Scala development.
- [`indent/scala.vim`](https://github.com/derekwyatt/vim-scala/blob/master/indent/scala.vim) – contains the logic for indenting.

These four files account for the bulk of the plugin, so you might as well get the entire thing. If you want to downsize things, then *removing* some files is usually easier than cherry-picking files until it works.

Comment: Concluding note is very sensible. Wanted to avoid going the plugin-way but I ended up losing an hour until I had it all figured out